# (Not) isekai manga which MC almost gets killed by the isekai princess to be reborn in her world

Tags: story-identification, manga, isekai, reincarnation

Anybody remembers the title of a manga about a MC who almost gets killed by another world's princess so he can be reincarnated as the hero in her world? (And ironically saved by the demons so he's still alive).

The story starts as typical harem protags, with him, his sister and all that. He meets a seemingly princess from another world who says she needs him to accompany her because she believes he's the destined hero to be reborn.

When the MC agrees, the princess almost kills him using a bus because that's the only way for him to go to her world. A demon girl saved her because she doesn't want him to be reincarnated.

I read it around a couple of years ago.

Comment: Can you remember any other details about this that you could [edit] in? Anymore of the plot? How he's saved? Why she knows to look for him? When you read this? etc.

Comment: @CountryCat If you are the OP (Ryuu Majin) on a different account, please consider checking out [how to merge your accounts](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/help/merging-accounts). Then you'll more easily be able to update your question, respond to comments here, etc.

Answer (score 4):

[image: Goodbye icon]

This manga is *Goodbye! Isekai Tensei!*
Description from [the website](https://myanimelist.net/store/manga/525/Goodbye_Im_Being_Reincarnated):

> High-school teen Yuya Kamigasaki lives a perfectly average life, when he isn't dropping in uninvited on his big-breasted friend next door. One day, a magical circle appears in his room, revealing Angelia, a princess from another world who offers to "reincarnate" him into the greatest hero that ever lived. This would-be hero's life is about to get a lot less boring and a whole lot more dangerous!

It has all your earmarks:

- well-endowed childhood friend who takes care of the main character (waking him up for school each day, cooking meals for him), calls him "little brother" because her birthday is technically before his
- has a gorgeous blonde princess from another world magic-circle-teleport into his bedroom; she believes the main character is the destined hero she was sent to find
- said princess tries to drive over main character the next day using a truck ([truck-kun](https://knowyourmeme.com/memes/truck-kun)) to kill him and have him reincarnate as the prophesied hero in her world; Yuuya will not be able to be the "destined hero" without reincarnation, he cannot go as he is now
- only to be stopped/diverted by the daughter of the demon king of the parallel world (and an unlucky goblin helper)

*Goodbye! Isekai Tensei!* only ran from August to October 2019, making 12 manga episodes (print cartoon episodes). It is unfinished, as the princess attempts multiple times, sometimes as slapstick humor, to kill the protagonist day after day, only to be stopped by misfortune or the demon king's daughter.